# Use an appropriate Half-Angle Formula to find the exact value of $\sin 105^\circ$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is this correct? $$\sin 105^\circ = \frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}{4}$$

Because $105^\circ$ is in the second quadrant the square root after the equal sign is $+$. However, because $\cos 210^\circ$ is negative, it value is negative  $-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

Is my thought process correct?

Also, can I factor out $\frac{1}{4}$?

Comment: This was a little messy, I probably made some mistake while formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You are right about the cosine of $210^\circ$.  The formula as currently written is not correct, there should be a $2$ in the denominator instead of a $4$. But the following would be correct:

$$\sqrt{\frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{4}},$$
and the current version is likely due to a typo.  It is more common to take the square root of the $4$, and write the answer as $\dfrac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}{2}$.

We now give a derivation, that undoubtedly goes along similar lines to yours.

By using the double-angle formula $\cos 2x=1-2\sin^2 x$, and letting $2x=210^{\circ}$, we then get 
$$2\sin^2 105^{\circ}=1-\left(-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)=\frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{2}.$$
This yields
$$\sin^2 105^{\circ}=\frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{4}.$$

Find the positive square root. We get $\sin 105^{\circ}=\dfrac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}{2}$.

**Remark:** In a comment, OP refers to a half angle formula. The formula we used can equally well be written as $\cos y=1-2\sin^2(y/2)$, or various equivalent forms. One of these forms is $\sin(y/2)=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos y}{2}}$. I prefer working from the double-angle formula each time. A difficulty with the plethora of equivalent formulas is that they get memorized, often imperfectly, and are not readily recalled when needed later.

Comment: Where did the 4 go?

Comment: No. Using the half angle formula.

Comment: We had a $4$ at the bottom when we divided by $2$. When we take the square root, it becomes a $2$. But I will add a line to make that clearer.

Comment: My answer is sin 105° = +1/2 √(2+√3)

Comment: The square root of 4 is 2? Where is the 2?

Comment: That is the same as what is written in the answer, with the $2$ in the denominator instead of in front as $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Your answer is not correct.

Comment: You may want to calculate $\frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}{2}$ with a calculator, also the sine of $105$ degrees. You will see that the calculator gives the same numbers.

Comment: I had a LaTeX glitch earlier, wrong placement of {}

Answer (score 1):

This is an equivalent way to get the same answer as above:

$\displaystyle\sin 105^{\circ}=\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos210^{\circ}}{2}}
=\sqrt{\frac{1-(-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})}{2}}=\sqrt{\frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{4}}=\frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}{2}$.

---

Notice that using the addition formula for the sine gives a different-looking answer:

$\sin 105^{\circ}=\sin(60^{\circ}+45^{\circ})=\sin60^{\circ}\cos45^{\circ}+\cos60^{\circ}\sin45^{\circ}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}=\frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\sin(105^\circ)
= \sin(90^\circ + 15^\circ)
= \cos(15^\circ)
= \sqrt{ \frac{1 + \cos(30^\circ)}{2}}
= \sqrt{ \frac{1 + \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{3}}{2}}
= \sqrt{ \frac{2 + \sqrt{3}}{4}}.
$$